# Error renombrando index.html con PHP

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de renombrar la "index.html" desde un archivo PHP (settings.php) con la siguiente linea:

```
rename ("/index.html", "/hidden.html");
```

Y me encuentro con la siguiente advertencia

> "Warning, read only file system in /srv/disk10/4521568/www/mydomain/admin/settings.php settings.php on line 28".

El problema es que el archivo no cambia de nombre.

¿Alguien podría ayudarme con esto?

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrarnos el error completo? Parece ser que tu archivo es de sólo lectura, en ese caso tendrías que darle permisos de lectura y escritura al archivo...

Comment: Hecho lo del error completo! pensé lo mismo pero le puse permisos 777, y tampoco funciona...

Answer (score 3):

Resuelto! lo que estaba mal parece que era la ruta al archivo! No borro la pregunta para advertir a otros desprevenidos! que cuando no encuentra el archivo en lugar de tirar "No file found..." puede devolvernos algún error que podría interpretarse asociado a los permisos!

Saludos y muchas gracias a todos!